# How to stop "Blockscheduler" on a particular end date?

Tags: python, flask, scheduler, apscheduler

I am using Blockscheduler() to run a solution (written in flask) on business days and it should eventually end on a particular mentioned date. My code looks like this

```
sched = BlockingScheduler()  
sched.add_job(job_function, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', 
hour=9, minute=13, end_date='2020-06-05 09:14:00')  

sched.start()
```

It should stop on that particular date but, somehow its not getting stopped.

Please, let me know where I am doing mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that the scheduler would automatically stop when all its jobs are done? It has no way of knowing if you'll add more jobs from other threads.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to shut down the scheduler after the job is complete, simply call `sched.shutdown(wait=False)` at the end of job_function.

Comment: Alex, thanks for your feedback, I want to stop at a specific date. That I can't do using end_date argument?

Comment: Using `end_date`, the schedule for that specific job will end then but that is not going to stop the scheduler.

Comment: then how will I stop or shut down the scheduler, using sched.shutdown only ?

Comment: Either schedule a job at the desired point of time that calls `sched.shutdown(wait=False)` or do as I said in the main answer and call it directly at the end of the scheduled job.

Answer (score 0):

I add another scheduled job to start at the end_date of the first job to shut down the scheduler

```
sched = BlockingScheduler()  
sched.add_job(job_function, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', 
hour=9, minute=13, end_date='2020-06-05 09:14:00')  

def end_job():
    sched.shutdown(wait=False)


sched.add_job(end_job, 'cron', start_date= '2020-06-05 09:14:00')

sched.start()
```